# Exclude unneccesarry jar in FAT jar using gradle

Tags: gradle

I am building the FAT jar using gradle-1.3 version and building the
FAT jar using this below properties

```
jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
 }
```

Dependencies AS FOLLOWS

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir:'/trunk/Solutions/Seismic/Source/Binaries/CommonFunctions/build/libs', include: '*.jar')
  compile "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.0.3"
  compile "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1"
  compile "commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.6"
  compile "commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.2"
  compile "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4"
  compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1"
  compile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4"
  compile "log4j:log4j:1.2.16"
  compile "com.vividsolutions:jts:1.8"
  compile "commons-net:commons-net:1.4.1"
  compile "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.0.3"
  compile "commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0.1"
  compile "org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:2.5-20081211"
  compile "org.apache.hbase:hbase:0.94.0"
  compile "org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.3"
}
```

But still by jar is included with following jar as reference

jay,
jline,
jni,
jnr,
jruby,
junit,
junit3.8.1

But i don't want to include these jars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude the dependencies by adding this to the bottom of your build:

```
configurations.all*.dependencies*.withType(ModuleDependency)*.each {
  it.exclude group: "org.jline", module: "jline"
  it.exclude ...
}
```

This will iterate over the dependencies of all configurations and exclude the modules that you don't want to include.

If you want to exclude all transitive dependencies, it is easier to set the transitivity to false for the compile configuration:

```
configurations.compile.transitive = false
```